# PostgreSQL - limit the total log size

Tags: postgresql, logging

I have a very simple requirement - PostgreSQL log directory should have fixed max size, e.g. max 10 GB for all PostgreSQL logs.

It can be achieved by creating fixed-size logs and using log rotation (e.g. rotate 10 log files, 1 GB per log file).

I tried to set this up using PostgreSQL logging configuration, but I didn't manage to achieve that. The problem is that "log_truncate_on_rotation" does not works for size-based rotation, only for time-based rotation.

So, my question is - can it be achieved using only PostgreSQL configuration or I have to use something else? If not, why PostgreSQL does not have that feature?

I have few options:

- set max file size to 1 GB using "log_rotation_size" property and then set CRON job which will remove oldest files if file count is above 10
- use logrotate utility, but I have to execute it more often than once per day

Comment: I believe you got it right - you need  a job. and cron can run jobs minutely - not only daily (regarding your last expression)

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you are right about no such feature - you need a cron

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

> log_truncate_on_rotation (boolean)
>
> When logging_collector is enabled, this parameter will cause
>   PostgreSQL to truncate (overwrite), rather than append to, any
>   existing log file of the same name. However, truncation will occur
>   only when a new file is being opened due to time-based rotation, **not
>   during server startup or size-based rotation**.

you can set up even minutely job to check the amount of logs:

```
* * * * * rm $(ls -t /PGDATA/pg_log/* | tail -n 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart of what others said, I would suggest to not reinvent the wheel.

Logrotate is usually invoked by cron and, even it may not be good idea to run it every minute, if you have a postgres logs size issue, you can add an additional cron entry that executes it conditionally depending of the logs dir size or free space (as you prefer).

**Caring about free space:**

Data:

```
joanmi@alpha:~$ sudo df -h /var/log/postgresql
S. fitxers                    Mida En ús Lliure  %Ús Muntat a
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root  229G  131G    87G  61% /
```

Pick:

```
joanmi@alpha:~$ sudo df -h /var/log/postgresql | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 5
131G
```

**Caring about used space:**

> Note that it is more expensive calculation.
>   It was fast enough for me because I have no big databases in this
>   machine (it is just my workstation).

Data:

```
joanmi@alpha:~$ sudo du -sh /var/log/postgresql/
76K     /var/log/postgresql/
```

Pick:

```
joanmi@alpha:~$ sudo du -sh /var/log/postgresql/ | cut -f 1
76K
```

And finally...

**Less user readable** (but easier to comparer in script):

```
joanmi@alpha:~$ sudo df /var/log/postgresql | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 5
137003128
```

or

```
joanmi@alpha:~$ sudo du -s /var/log/postgresql/ | cut -f 1
76
```

> **NOTE:** I used sudo to avoid permission issues.
>   In a root cron job it can be removed.

**Example:**

Regarding free space:

This outputs nothing (if you have at least 100k free):

```
[[ \
    $(df /var/log/postgresql | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 5) \
    -gt 100 \
]] \
    || echo 'Logrotate should be performedd!!'
```

This outputs `Logrotate should be performedd!!` (except if you have a really big disk ;-)):

```
[[ \
    $(df /var/log/postgresql | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 5) \
    -gt 100000000000000000000 \
]] \
    || echo 'Logrotate should be performedd!!'
```