# PostgreSQL log rotation size based

Tags: postgresql, logging

I try to limit PostgreSQL logs based on size.
I have tried to configure logs configuration like that:

```
log_destination = 'csvlog'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = '/var/log/pgsql'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'
log_truncate_on_rotation = on 
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_rotation_size = 100kB
```

The logs rotate based on age works well, but the sized based rotation doesn't seem to work.

I have limited the log size to 100kB but the csv file's size is growing up to 600MB.
Eventually, there is only one file created by the 'size based rotation' which is 1.5MB (`postgresql-Sun.csv-20210502.gz`).
How can I make the log rotation work based on size?

Postgresql version - 12.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458135/postgresql-limit-the-total-log-size

Comment: Since the name can't change, what would it rotate to?  In order for size-based rotation to work, your naming scheme needs the capacity for more resolution than log_rotation_age needs.

Comment: The part you are missing is [Log rotation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHERE) `log_truncate_on_rotation` "However, truncation will occur only when a new file is being opened due to time-based rotation, not during server startup or size-based rotation." In that section there is an example of how to do what you want using @jjanes suggestion.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, the part you are missing is [Log rotation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHERE)  log_truncate_on_rotation "However, truncation will occur only when a new file is being opened due to time-based rotation, not during server startup or size-based rotation." In that section there is an example of how to do what you want using @jjanes suggestion.

Comment: Thank You very much!!! 
This did help but I ran into another issue... Is there a way to compress the old logs when a knew one is created. and how to delete them after a set amount of time

Comment: You will need to create a script or point a program at the logs to do this. You might want to look at `logrotate`.